NullPointerException thrown by LayerManager.persistLayers
We see a NullPointerException which is caused by LayerManager.persistLayers of compose.
The problem is that we can't reproduce this error. The exception is thrown only on screens where NO Compose is used. It happens on all kind of devices and android versions (starting from Android 11).
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
       at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.layer.LayerManager.persistLayers(LayerManager.android.kt:116)
       at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.layer.LayerManager.updateLayerPersistence(LayerManager.java:136)
       at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidGraphicsContext$componentCallback$1$onTrimMemory$1.onPreDraw(AndroidGraphicsContext.android.kt:79)
       at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1204)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:4723)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:3288)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:11344)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1689)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1698)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1153)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1079)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1646)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
        

I'm using the following version of compose ui:
{ group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui", version = "1.7.0-rc01" }
and this version of lifecycle:
{ group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-compose", version = "2.8.4" }
Has anyone experienced this Exception as well and has a hint on how to prevent it? Is it introduced by a buggy library version?

I also see these and recently started.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/343750859?pli=1 related

this is not any library issue check your code you've pass any null object in your component kindly debug your code

Hey Ayann. I am curious to know how are you so sure that it's not library? We don't directly access this code so no way to directly pass something null here.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks @HBB20 for the linked issue report.
It seems that this issue has been fixed in 1.7.0-beta04 of compose libs.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/343750859#comment41
For now I can't see any new crashes of this type since I've release our app with 1.7.0-rc01. All crashes happende 1.7.0-beta03 and below..
-> Update your compose libs to latest stable version 1.7.0 and the crash will be gone
